# Large Image Causes Crashing xCode

Tags: iphone, xcode, image, ios, uiimageview

I have a 6000x3000 px image that is in a zoomable view in my xCode project. In the initial view, a button is pressed to access the view with the large, zoomable image. This all works fine, except for the time that is taken to "load" the image often times causes a crash in the app, especially when I am testing on older devices (it seems to work fine most of the time on my 4G itouch). Is there any way to "pre-render" this one large image, or anything else that I can do to prevent crashing?

Comment: Run the application in debug mode and add the exception to your post, it might help get a more relevant answer.

Comment: Have tried an indexed color range ? That could work with old devices I believe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do the math: 6000 x 3000 x 3 (red green blue) = 54,000,000 bytes = 51.5MiB of raw data. The normal image handling has a lot of overhead and that simply takes too much memory.

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706152/displaying-very-large-images-on-the-ipad) the solution is to use a CATiledLayer. As far as I have understood it, you need to divide your large image into smaller parts and draw these smaller parts with the help of CATiledLayer.

**Edit:** Here's a quote from the UIView class reference:

> Note: In iOS 2.x, the maximum size of a UIView object is 1024 x 1024 points. In iOS 3.0 and later, views are no longer restricted to this maximum size but are still limited by the amount of memory they consume. It is in your best interests to keep view sizes as small as possible. Regardless of which version of iOS is running, you should consider tiling any content that is significantly larger than the dimensions the screen.

Read: If it's larger, use a CATiledLayer to draw smaller parts.

Comment: Sorry, but my image is says that it's only 3 megabytes when I click "Get Info"...is that right?

Comment: @user634324: *Compressed* it may only be 3MB, but to display it needs to be decompressed. And then the memory consumption is simple *width* x *height* x *depth*. For a normal image, the depth is 3 bytes (one each for red, green and blue). If it's an image with an alpha channel (transparency) then the depth is 4 bytes.